# The easiest DHT to implement

Tags: python, p2p, dht

Which Distributed Hash Table (DHT) is easiest to implement in Python? Any good example that is not bloated?

I not am looking for a definition of DHT because I am more oriented and focused on design and implementation of such.

Comment: Do you mean something like CouchDB?

Comment: CouchDB is very-high-level for my needs because I am looking for DHT only. What part of CouchDB do you suggest to check?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you are focused on implementation, rather than looking for an out-of-the-box solution, this article might help a bit:  http://www.linuxjournal.com/article/6797

Comment: this is a great example, but it isn't complete

Comment: in combination with http://www.bittorrent.org/beps/bep_0005.html was very useful for me!

Answer (score 11):

In my job I'm working with [entagled](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/entangled/0.1). I can't say it's great code, but it seems to be the only [Kademlia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kademlia) implementation for Python around.

I think Kademlia has become the default DHT for most applications today, because it's quite simple and has fast lookups. At least in the academic world that I've seen so far.

Comment: I have used __entagled__, and I totally agree with you that it isn't the greatest code, but it works. Which one do you prefer Kademlia or Chord?

Comment: I only worked with Kademlia, but I think Kademlia is a direct successors to Chord. It just has a simpler metric to find nodes and uses more parallelism in lookups.

Comment: For clarity of logic, this python open source code is good.  It uses asyncio: https://github.com/bmuller/kademlia

Answer (score 5):

You might want to check out [DHTBot](https://github.com/gsko/DHTBot). It's a python implementation of the BitTorrent MDHT and is written using twisted, a high-level python networking library.

(**Disclaimer: I am the author of DHTBot)

Answer (score 4):

You may also check [btdht](https://github.com/nitmir/btdht) that doesn't use twisted and is useful to sniff Bittorrent DHT.