# Which DHT implementations are compatible with Python 3.x?

Tags: python, python-3.x, p2p, dht

Following on from [this question about DHTs in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1704646/the-easiest-dht-to-implement), my question is the same except that I'm developing on Python 3.x - I only want to know about implementations of the DHT concept which are known to work with Python 3.

There seem to be plenty of DHT products, for example  Khashmir, however as far as I'm aware nobody has bothered to make these available to Python 3.x.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you'll get simultaneous 2.6 and 3.x support - that is not what Guido is recommending. To do that they'd have to maintain two equivalent parallel code-lines, because the same code is unlikely to work on both python 2 and 3.

Comment: That's true, but only in a very specific sense. :) http://python3porting.com/strategies.html