# Which Python 2.x DHT implementation is going to be easiest to port to Python 3.x?

Tags: python, dht

Previously I asked [which DHT implementations are compatible with Python 3.x](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1708315/which-dht-implementations-are-compatible-python-3-x) - StackOverflow's answer confirmed my worst fear: So far nobody has released a Python 3.x compatible Distributed Hash Table implementation. That means it's to roll up my sleeves and get to work myself.

My project does not necessarily require the highest performance, it simply needs to be a true DHT.

Since this feature is not core to my project (but could be truly awesome) I do not want to get bogged down tweaking ultimate performance. Nor do I want to spend a lot of time fixing somebody else's bugs.

I just want pick up the DHT implementation that's going to be the easiest to work with and then port it to 3.x. In theory this work should not require a profound knowledge of the way any spesific implementation work.

So given all of the above, which of the many python 2.x DHT implementations are going to be my best bet to start with?

Comment: I'm currently working on a DHT for Python 3. I'll post links here if I remember in a few months.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try running 2to3 on each of them, then run the resulting code.  If one of them works, then it was the easiest to port.  If none of them do, then take a guess based on which of their errors you understand best.

Comment: Good answer, however the prize will go to somebody who has actual inside knowledge of the various implementations. I was hoping to save having to download every implementation and investigate it for myself!

Comment: I know, it's not as good as a specific answer, but DHT is a fairly specialized tool, so you may have few experts to choose from.

Comment: Thanks, I think that's the best I'm going to get. You win. :-)